# How to modify an old joomla website to remove a dangerous link flagged by google

Tags: joomla, malware

A client told me his old website running on Joomla was flagged by google for having links to a malicious website. The website was blocked with the typical red security warning in google Chrome. I redirected the website to a temp page, but my client wants to bring back the old website while we work on something new.

However, my local machine and server are running Windows Server. I have the original files of the website and database. Is there a quick way I could remove the links (the google tool only mentions the website "mosaictriad.com") from the Joomla page from my machine? I've tried doing a crtl+f for mosaictriad.com in the sql file but didn't find anything.

Thanks for your opinion on what I should do next, the objective is simply to quickly clear the website from the security warning and send it back to the people managing his old server.

PS i don't have direct access to his server, only the files associated with his joomla website.

```
Additional details given my google:

Some pages on this website redirect visitors to dangerous websites that install malware on visitors' computers, including: mosaictriad.com.


Dangerous websites have been sending visitors to this website, including: navis.be and umblr.com.
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is a way. You need to register in google webmaster tools. Register your site. Add the sitelinks. Ask google to rescan your website. They will remove it within 24 hours if scan result is negative for malwares.

Comment: Hi Amit,

I know about the webmaster tools. What i'm asking is how to modify the joomla website so it doesn't contain the malicious links without having a server running php at my disposal.

Comment: Now I got it once you expanded your question. The possible solution seems to scan it with anti malware scanner. You can also create a dummy website from the backup you have. get it scanned through online scanners.

Answer (score 1):

Running the virus scanner on your local machine over the files may be able to detect some malicious files.

Alternatively, restore the website to a temporary folder on the web and use a commercial scanning service to help identify and clean the website. I use and recommend [myjoomla.com](http://myjoomla.com) but there are other services such as [sucuri.net](http://sucuri.net).

Answer (score 1):

I think your strategy is wrong - you should quickly cleanup the website (try overwriting the core files with files from a fresh Joomla install) and you should then secure the website. Once you do that, you should contact Google through the Webmaster tools for a reconsideration request (this typically takes a few days to process if it's the first offense). Once Google approves your reconsideration request, then the red flag should be removed and the website should be accessible by everyone.